# System of differential equations with a NOT positive definite matrix (SVD?)

Tags: systems-of-equations, positive-definite, svd

After solving the dynamics of a system, I arrived at an apparently simple system of differential equations of the form:

$$
\tau \frac{d}{dt}\vec{w}=Q\vec{w}+\vec{c}
$$

where $ \vec{c}\neq\vec{c}(t) $ and $Q$ is a NOT positive definite matrix.

Numerical simulations show that this equation is indeed correct for the system I am modelling.

If $Q$ would be positive definite, the solution would be trivial, the dynamics of $\vec{w}$ would be a linear sum of the eigenvectors of $Q$, with separate odes for the coefficients. I would like to know if there is a known similar approach for the case in which $Q$ is not positive definite. I have been trying (for days) to solve it by doing SVD for $Q$:

$$
Q=USV^T
$$

and then trying to arrive at a system of the form:

$$
\tau \frac{d}{dt}\vec{\tilde{w}}=S\vec{\tilde{w}}+\vec{\tilde{c}}
$$

where $\tilde{w}$ is an appropriate transformation of $w$ that satisfies this equation ($S$ is a diagonal matrix of the singular values of $Q$). Of course, I haven't been able to find such a transformation.

Ideally, I would like to know if there is an established approach for this problem (maybe I am missing something big...), or at least if it is known to be a problem without a general solution. You would be my saviour and I will be eternally grateful for your aid!

Comment: You can still apply the eigendecomposition approach even if the matrix is not positive definite.

Comment: Are you sure? In this case, the eigenvectors of Q do not form a basis, so we cannot write w in terms of the eigenvectors of Q and solve the equation in this way. Do you have any link to proof that this is the case?

Comment: Ah, so your matrix is not merely not-positive-definite but actually defective (a very special case!). In that case the procedure needs some extra steps, see e.g. http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/RepeatedEigenvalues.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming $Q$ is invertible, the general solution is 
$$ \vec{w} = - Q^{-1} \vec{c} + \exp(Q t/\tau) \vec{v}$$
for arbitrary vectors $\vec{v}$.  There are many ways of calculating the [matrix exponential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_exponential).

Comment: Thank you! I will look into this :)